# HTML 5 Load Video After Page Has Loaded

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

Hi I am just wondering how I can load a HTML 5 video after the page has actually loaded? At the moment my HTML 5 video currently stops the user from actually using the site until the video has loaded however I would like to make it so that it just shows an image until the video loads and then autoplay it?

Can anybody think of a way that this can be done?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Type your question title into Google BEFORE typing it in here, and you'll be pleasantly surprised by the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$(window).load(function(){ // video code });`.Because it executes after the page is loaded completely.